# Activating MyFiles app for a URI result

Tags: android

there must be a way to do that, as in the clock alarm app that is built in android, when you press on the change alert button, it opens 2 possibilities, one uses RingtoneManager, and on the other you can choose to find a ringtone using My Files to get an alert ringtone, I want to do the same in my app... how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your manifest.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This is untested, but i believe it should work. You just have to tell your app to listen for that action.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER